# How to describe the Possible Routes between 2 Nodes using Pseudo code

Tags: path, routes, nodes, pseudocode, dijkstra

I'am trying to develop an algorithm using Pseudo code to display all possible routes between 2 Nodes. I have looked at the dijkstra algorithm but I'am having some difficulty trying to create an algorithm using only Pseudo Code.

Possible Routes Between node 7 and 5

I have identified all the possible Routes (Without passing the same node twice)

7 -> 4 -> 5

7 -> 6 -> 2 ->1 -> 8 -> 5

7-> 6 -> 4 -> 5

7 -> 6 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 5

Set of Nodes: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Link between Nodes 1+2, 1+3, 1+8, 2+6, 3+5, 4+5, 4+6, 4+7, 5+8, 6+7.

Answer (score 0):

> Using DFS: The idea is to do Depth First Traversal of given directed
>   graph. Start the traversal from source. Keep storing the visited
>   vertices in an array say ‘path[]’. If we reach the destination vertex,
>   print contents of path[]. The important thing is to mark current
>   vertices in path[] as visited also, so that the traversal doesn’t go
>   in a cycle.

```
Java Implementation:

// Prints all paths from
    // 's' to 'd'
    public void printAllPaths(int s, int d) 
    {
        boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[v];
        ArrayList pathList = new ArrayList<>();

        //add source to path[]
        pathList.add(s);

        //Call recursive utility
        printAllPathsUtil(s, d, isVisited, pathList);
    }

    // A recursive function to print
    // all paths from 'u' to 'd'.
    // isVisited[] keeps track of
    // vertices in current path.
    // localPathList<> stores actual
    // vertices in the current path
    private void printAllPathsUtil(Integer u, Integer d,
                                    boolean[] isVisited,
                            List localPathList) {

        // Mark the current node
        isVisited[u] = true;

        if (u.equals(d)) 
        {
            System.out.println(localPathList);
        }

        // Recur for all the vertices
        // adjacent to current vertex
        for (Integer i : adjList[u]) 
        {
            if (!isVisited[i])
            {
                // store current node 
                // in path[]
                localPathList.add(i);
                printAllPathsUtil(i, d, isVisited, localPathList);

                // remove current node
                // in path[]
                localPathList.remove(i);
            }
        }

        // Mark the current node
        isVisited[u] = false;
    }
```

You can check another ways here https://efficientcodeblog.wordpress.com/2018/02/15/finding-all-paths-between-two-nodes-in-a-graph/